# How to break inheritance from parent element class in CSS?

Tags: html, css, class, inheritance, styles

I have three levels of elements in HTML. And I have CSS like L1 > L3 { /some css/ } and L2 > L3 { /some css/ }. HTML takes both css to L3 element. I dont want L1 > L3 CSS instead of removing it is there any way to break the inheritance?

```
L1 > L3 
{ 
/some css/ 
}
L2 > L3 
{ 
/some css/ 
}
```

Comment: You have to override the L3 css rules that are present in the first L1 >L3 rules.

Comment: could you show the HTML? need to see the structure

Comment: Your current example can't cause the behaviour you describe - a direct child of L1 cannot also be a direct child of L2. So can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element will inherit a value for a property from its parent if it has:

```
some_property: inherit;
```

Many elements have this value as the default for many properties.

If you don't want it to inherit, then **set a different value**.

```css
div { color: red; }
p { color: blue; }
span { color: initial }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    2
    <span>3</span>
  </p>
</div>
```